# 4 color theorem, attempted disproof

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[4 color theorem attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7K6.png)

I recently found out about the numberphile youtube channel, one of their videos referenced the four color theorem, and as with anybody else when they first find out about this theorem, attempted to break it. In my attempt, see linked photo, I am unable to color the map using only 4 colors, but would love to be proven wrong. Can anyone else see the solution that I am not seeing?

Comment: There are many such "disproofs" of this sort at this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995663/four-color-theorem-disproof), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247841/how-can-this-planar-map-be-coloured-using-4-colours?noredirect=1&lq=1). Have a look, I am sure it will clarify then.

Comment: It is very easy to colour if you start with the middle cross and the two parts of the ellipse, which need three different colours. Then you are left with a few separate regions to fill in.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
A picture is worth a thousand words, right?